# Accessing BigQuery from Presto

Tags: google-bigquery, presto

I'm curious if there is a way to connect BigQuery to one's Presto catalog. I don't see anything from either project that references the other and nothing in Presto's roadmap to suggest that a BigQuery connector would be forthcoming. BigQuery has ODBC/JDBC drivers which is promising, and Presto has Postgres and MySQL connectors but I'm not seeing a way to connect one to the other. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing built in already, but it shouldn't be difficult to extend the presto-base-jdbc connector to support BigQuery if you wanted.  This is how the MySQL, Postgres and Redshift connectors are built.